# Speed up code to get data from multiple sheets to another

Tags: vba, performance, loops

Please advise regarding reduce the time for the below code, noted that the total row in sheet is about 40,000 row and the time it takes the code to finish more than 40 minutes.

I have three sheets; the 1st is the target sheet "PO" and the 2nd and 3rd are the source ones "PR" & "CTG. List"

```
Private Sub cmdPO_Click()
'Prepare PO sheet
SpeedOn
Dim zrng, rng As Range
Dim LR As Long

On Error Resume Next
With Sheets("PO")
LR = .Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("AA3:AA" & LR) = vbNullString
.Range("AE3:AG" & LR) = vbNullString

For Each rng In .Range("B3:B" & LR)
    Set zrng = Sheets("PR").Columns(19).Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
        If Not zrng Is Nothing Then rng.Offset(0, 25) = zrng.Offset(0, -17)
        
        If rng.Offset(0, -1) = "ASEER" Or rng.Offset(0, -1) = "DAMMAM" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 29) = rng.Offset(0, 5)
        Else
            rng.Offset(0, 29) = Left(rng.Offset(0, 2), 2)
        End If
        
        Set zrng = Sheets("CTG. List").Columns(1).Find(rng.Offset(0, 29), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
            If Not zrng Is Nothing Then
                rng.Offset(0, 30) = zrng.Offset(0, 1)
                rng.Offset(0, 31) = zrng.Offset(0, 2)
            Else
                rng.Offset(0, 30) = "": rng.Offset(0, 31) = ""
            End If
Next rng
End With
End Sub

Option Explicit
 
Public glb_origCalculationMode As Integer
 
Sub SpeedOn(Optional StatusBarMsg As String = "Running macro...")
    glb_origCalculationMode = Application.Calculation
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Cursor = xlWait
        .StatusBar = StatusBarMsg
        .EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably a lot faster to do this in memory using `Variant` arrays.

Comment: Stepping through the sheet cell by cell evaluating multiple criteria is hella slow. It is much faster to work with ranges. You should figure out a way to get your selection criteria into separate columns and then use AdvancedFilter to do the copy.

Comment: Match() is much faster then Find()

Comment: Thanks dears
Please BigBen and Tim; Can you illustrate more about this please